# How to login mysql with exec.Command

Tags: mysql, go, command, exec

I want to login MySql with exec.Command of GoLang, I am sure that I can login success, but I can not enter into MySql script interface.

The program do not output any error, it exit after finished, that is not what I expected, I want to enter into the mysql script interface.

The code is like this:

```
    host := "localhost"
    user := "root"
    password := "root"

    cmd := exec.Command("mysql","-h"+host,"-u"+user,"-p"+password)
    cmd.Output()
```

I want to see this after the program run:

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>

then I can write mysql script continue.
thanks!

Comment: Why are you doing this? It would be much better to use the standard mysql library.

Comment: I want to write a command line tool, with it I can login mysql, transport data between tables on different server, etc. of course I can use mysqldump,or I can write some  command in shell file, but I want to this command tool undertake more jobs, so I want implement it with GoLang.

Comment: That's great. Write in in Go. Just don't use exec.Command--use the standard mysql library instead.

Comment: this looks like a nice starter: http://go-database-sql.org/

Answer (score 0):

After my trying, the answer is this:

```
cmd := exec.Command("mysql","-h"+host,"-u"+user,"-p"+password,"-P"+port)
cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
err := cmd.Run()
```

only need give os.Stdin to cmd.Stdin, then we will enter into mysql script interface.